# How to calculate D0->K+K- decay with QCD factorization?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, particle-physics, quarks, mesons

I am studying the decay of D0->K+K- and I calculated the result of Branching Ratio by Naive QCD and I wrote all the equations for amplitude and branching Ration and Hamiltonian and... for this decay but my problem is I can not solve them for QCD factorization and I can not find any source helping me and knowing the way I am doing this is correct or not.

Could you tell me some sources for this decay if you know? I checked all other decays but I found nothing helpful.